# JMETER: JMeter 5.3 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. During Jmeter execution

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jmeter, amazon-redshift, jmeter-5.0

I have configured a Testplan using Jmeter shown below in the image and have been using the CLI to run my parallel load tests. *MAC USER*

[image: testpla]
[image]

I have configured a connection with my AWS RedShift database, when I check my queries monitoring, all of the queries get stuck in a Running state.

[image: rds]

After some time, on my terminal, i get the following error: **JMeter 5.3 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.**

I have gone into my bin/jemeter file and have made the memory changes but I am still facing the same issue.

[image: memory change]

When I run the same queries from DBeaver, the queries are run and completed and can be seen on Redshift query monitoring.

How can I solve the memory problem in order for the queries to run without being stuck in a running state?

Below is the Error i am getting even after increasing the heap size to 5 gigabytes.

```
WARNING: package sun.awt.X11 not in java.desktop
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using //Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/redshit-test/test-redhsift.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Wed Dec 02 14:53:17 GMT 2020 (1606920797442)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid35596.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [3071802740 bytes in 3.747 secs]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which exact [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html)? There are several possible reasons:

- Lack of [heap space](https://medium.com/@abigaelse2/jvm-memory-heap-80075e4ffeb7), if this is the case - you're looking at the right place, just make sure that your changes are applied
- [GC Overhead Limit Exceeded](https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) occurs when the GC executing almost 100% of time not leaving the program any chance to do its job
- [Requested array size exceeds VM limit](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit) when the program tries to create too large objects
- [Unable to Create New Native Thread](https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshoot-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new) when the program cannot create a new thread because the operating system doesn't allow it
- and so on

It's not possible to state what's wrong without seeing your full test plan (at least screenshot) as it might be the case you added [tons of Listeners and each of them stores large DB query response in memory](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (definitely not in the form of screenshot) which in the majority of cases contains either the cause of the problem or at least a clue

Comment: I have removed all  Listeners from the test plan and as it only contains the JDBC requests that I have added. The outodMemoryError is linked with the heap space, I have increased the size but it still takes a long time over an hour to complete all the queries that i have set in the threshold. i have increased the heap space to 5 gigabytes

Comment: After increasing the heap size to 5gigbytes, i get the following erorr: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space